# A characterisitc polynomial is $z^4(z-1)^3(z-2)^2$ . How to work out dimension of null$(T-2I)^9$

Tags: linear-algebra

I honestly have no idea how you would do this.

I do know that I would a $9\times 9$ matrix with $ 0, 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2$ on diagonal entries has the above ch. polynomial.

Have no idea where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$\text{Multiplicity of $\lambda$} =\dim \text{null} (T-\lambda I)^{\dim V}.$$

From the characteristic polynomial, you know that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ is equal to $2$. Hence, $$\dim \text{null} (T-2I)^{9}=2.$$

Comment: Oh *facepalm*. Is there a proof of why this is or is it just  purely a definition?

Comment: And If I wanted to know dim null$(T-3I)^9$ that would be zero because 3 is not an eigenvector? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Can you cite a reference of the above result. I want to learn.

Comment: @user289419: Yes that is correct! And see page 171 of http://php.scripts.psu.edu/users/m/k/mkc5021/ebook.pdf

Comment: Axler is unusual in defining multiplicity in this fashion.  Usually, eigenvalues are thought of in terms of determinants, which Axler tends to avoid wherever possible.